# Как можно ввести из edit функцию?

Tags: график, delphi

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax, Hx, Hy, h, x, y : Real;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    Xmax:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
    Xmin:=StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);

    Ymax:=StrToFloat(Edit3.Text);
    Ymin:=StrToFloat(Edit4.Text);

    Hx:=StrToFloat(Edit5.Text);
    Hy:=StrToFloat(Edit6.Text);
    H:=StrToFloat(Edit7.Text);
  except
    MessageBeep(Error);
    MessageDlg('Неверно заданы параметры', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
  end;

  Chart1.BottomAxis.Minimum:=Xmin;
  Chart1.BottomAxis.Maximum:=Xmax;

  Chart1.LeftAxis.Minimum:=Ymin;
  Chart1.LeftAxis.Maximum:=Ymax;

  Chart1.BottomAxis.Increment:=Hx;
  Chart1.LeftAxis.Increment:=Hy;

  Form1.Button1Click(Sender);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Series1.Clear;
  x:=Xmin;
  While x<=Xmax do
  begin

    y:=StrToFloat(Edit8.Text);

    Series1.AddXY(x, y, '', clTeeColor);
    x:=x+h;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно ввести из edit функцию?

Comment: Написать парсер алгебраических выражений.

Answer (score 1):

нужен интерпритатор функций хотя бы элементарный, я бы конечно рекомендовал использовал готовый 
RemObjects Pascal Script III
Copyright (C) 2000-2012 by Carlo Kok (ck@carlo-kok.com)
полный  pascal в вашем приложении

Answer (score 0):

Функция, я так понимаю, для отображения в TChart в виде графика? Если тип функции не меняется, разбросай коэффициенты по edit-ам и высчитывай новые значения у-ка через каждый шаг h по оси абсцисс.

Comment: Да, функция для отображения графиков. Мне нужно чтобы пользователь вводил любую функцию в Edit и она строилась в Tchart.